# Add orocos libraries to ROS project

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I have a problem with adding libraries, orocos components to ROS project. In CMakeLists.txt I add line:

```
include_directories(/home/user/my_lib_orocos)
```

But I still can't add any library from that folder to .cpp files, compiler doesn't see it. In addition, these folder isn't in the same path as my ROS project.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60599/add-orocos-libraries-to-ros-project/) by [Roboticus](https://answers.ros.org/users/4649/roboticus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2013-04-16**:
are they custom libraries or orocos libraries such as bfl or kdl ? Which ros distro are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Roboticus,

I have added these lines for a ros project using the LabJack U3 Modul. It also has a separate library.

- #directory where the library file is in
- link_directories(/home/thomas/projects/labjack/exodrive/liblabjackusb)
- #add the cpp files of your project
- rosbuild_add_executable(labjack src/LabJack.cpp src/... some more files ...)
- #link the library to the project (name of lib file: liblabjackusb.so.2.5.2
- target_link_libraries (labjack labjackusb)

As you can see the library is written without the pre-string "lib" and without the version number and type at the end. So the filename "liblabjackusb.so.2.5.2" will become -> "labjackusb".

The command you used: include_directories(/home/user/my_lib_orocos) is more or less to describe where the header files are.

Hope this helps you with your problem.

Best regards,
zumili

---

Originally posted by [zumili](https://answers.ros.org/users/3935/zumili/) with karma: 141 on 2013-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to build your own Orocos based components/packages, please take a look at http://www.orocos.org/wiki/orocos/toolchain/component-packages to learn how this is done.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) with karma: 543 on 2013-04-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1